# Incrementing Text in Circular Progress Bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, progress-bar

```
private void _btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _label1.Hide();
        _label2.Hide();
        _label3.Hide();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            _circularprogressbar.Value = i;
            _circularprogressbar.Update();
        }
    }

    private void LoadingScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _circularprogressbar.Value = 0;
        _circularprogressbar.Minimum = 0;
        _circularprogressbar.Maximum = 100;
    }
}
```

}

This is my code. What i want to do is, i want to have a text inside the progress bar that shows the percentage of the progress from 1 to 100 percent.
what can i add to my code?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

That `Thread.Sleep(5)` is blocking your entire UI thread. If you want to have your UI responsive, while the progress takes place, you need to make a separate thread for it. Something like this:

```
private void _btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _label1.Hide();
    _label2.Hide();
    _label3.Hide();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                _circularprogressbar.Value = i;
                _circularprogressbar.Update();
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

Note that you will need t use Invoke to BeginInvoke to access UI components from inside that thread.

Comment: what is invoke for?

Comment: Executing stuff in UI thread. If you try to muck around with UI objects from another thread, you will get cross-thread violation. Actually, access to anything outside the thread must be cautious and can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do:

```
private void _btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _label1.Hide();
        _label2.Hide();
        _label3.Hide();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            _circularprogressbar.Value = i;
            _percent_lable_name.Text = string.Format("{0}%", _circularprogressbar.Value);
            _circularprogressbar.Update();
        }
    }

    private void LoadingScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _circularprogressbar.Value = 0;
        _circularprogressbar.Minimum = 0;
        _circularprogressbar.Maximum = 100;
    }
}
```

See if that helps you!

Thanks

**Techcraft7 :)**